# Ubuntu 18.04 LTS live USB hangs

Tags: boot, dual-boot, uefi, live-usb

I'm using a Dell Inspiron Gaming and I wanted to dual-boot Linux. I've set a dual boot before in another notebook and it worked perfectly, but I can't get the live USB it to work properly on this one.

Every Ubuntu flavor I try hangs on a different point:

- I've got far with Lubuntu, it only hanged when I tried to shut down the computer.
- With Mate version I can's get past the try/install screen, whenever I hit "try" it freezes and I am forced to shutdown using the power button
- Ubuntu, Ubuntu Budgie and Kubuntu freeze directly on boot and I'm forced to use the power button to shutdown

I don't know what's causing the problem but I have some guesses:

- I didn't manage to boot directly on the USB, I'm on Windows 10 and I am using the "advanced recovery options" that let me restart using a USB drive (the boot is set to UEFI, I really couldn't manage to set the boot order as the USB drive doesn't appear listed as an option), could that be it?
- I have an Nvidia GTX1050Ti, I've heard that sometimes this problem is caused by the drivers and it's solved using the `nomodeset`, but I couldn't find how to set it in the USB live boot.

The pendrive works, it’s the same I used to install Linux in my previous notebook

I am very new to Linux with little to no programming/computer stuff background, so it may be really newbie questions.

How can I get the live USB to work properly?

Comment: Some Linux live USB apps do not make a drive that works with UEFI, mkusb for Ubuntu and UNetbootin for Windows both work with both BIOS and UEFI. nomodeset: when booting a grub type install, press shift while booting, when the boot page comes up press F6, after the -- type <space>nomodeset, this can be automated using grub.cfg. Or with a UNetbootin drive press Tab at the boot menu and type <space>nomodeset, this can be automated editing syslinux.cfg.

Comment: I'm using Rufus to make the usb, but I am going to try to use UNetbootin and the shift and F6 while the usb boots.

Comment: For Rufus edit /isolinux/txt.cfg